# Show admin labels for only one country via CartoCSS in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapping, mapbox, cartography, cartocss

I'd like to show admin labels for only one country on a map of Latin America. I'm new to CartoCSS and can't figure it out. I tried inspecting the labels and couldn't discern any hierarchy in the OSM ids that might help.